# How to manipulate characters and objects in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am new to programming in LibGDX and I'm currently working on a simple arcade game. And I would like to know how should I properly create a main character who just has to run and jump? Should I create a new class for him and implement some method? As for now, I have only two classes, MyGame where I handle the other game states and PlayState where I draw the background and objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a [Sprite](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html), you can control it easily.

```
SpriteBatch batch;
Sprite sprite;//Main character

@Override
public void create(){        
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/text.png")));
}

@Override
public void render(){
    //Add logic to control the main character...

    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

If you want to create more methods you could try extending the [Actor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html) class too, this way it can be reused.

```
public class MyActor extends Actor{
    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/tex.png"));
    float actorX = 0, actorY = 0;
    public MyActor(){
        addListener(new InputListener(){//Receive events
                public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){//Check your run and jump buttons
            //...
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){//Draw it
        batch.draw(texture,actorX,actorY);
    }
    @Override
    public void act(float delta){//Update it
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But the thing is, I want my character to jump or do some actions for example, for this, I need to use an update() method, but I don't know where does this method exist, or should I create in on my own?

Comment: Yes, you use the [Input Listener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputListener.html) to detect whenever an action like pressing a button happens and on the render() or act() methods you update the position.